# Remove all collections except some of them

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to run remove script on all collection except some of them.

The whole collections which don't want remove are from only one(i.e. XYZ) client so every time the collections from XYZ client's collections will increase. thats why I am not able to fix the removal with below script. because every time I need to mention increased collections over there.

```
    // making variable for date before 93 days
var monthdate = new Date();
monthdate.setDate(monthdate.getDate() - 93);

//Date format should be : '2019/09/16'  (yyyy/MM/dd)

function objectIdWithTimestamp(timestamp) {
    // Convert string date to Date object (otherwise assume timestamp is a date)
    if (typeof(timestamp) == 'string') {
        timestamp = new Date(timestamp);
    }
    // Convert date object to hex seconds since Unix epoch
    var hexSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp/1000).toString(16);
    // Create an ObjectId with that hex timestamp
    var constructedObjectId = ObjectId(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");
    return constructedObjectId
}
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c) {
    if(c.match("AggBalances_") && 
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_910")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_934")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_966")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_981")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_999")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_1045")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_1073")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_1094")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_1105")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("AggBalances_1068")) 
    ) {    
   db.getCollection(c).remove({ _id: { $lt: objectIdWithTimestamp(monthdate) } })
        print(c);
    }
    else if(c.match("RecBalance_") &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_910")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_934")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_966")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_981")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_999")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_1045")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_1073")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_1094")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_1105")) &&
    (!c.endsWith("RecBalance_1068"))
    ) { 
   db.getCollection(c).remove({ _id: { $lt: objectIdWithTimestamp(monthdate) } })
        print(c);
    }
  });
```

@jiri
Where do you get the names of the collections that you want to leave untouched?

```
var setupArr = [];

db.setup.aggregate([
                     { $match: { "ClientID": "5c1cf5e29bbee71ac083b312" } }, // XYZ client Setup codes
                     { $project: { "SetupCode": 1} }
                     ]).forEach(function(user){
//print(user.SetupCode);
setupArr.push(user.SetupCode)
});

print(setupArr)
```

from here I am getting these name of collections_setupcodes but not able to skip them using this (**setupArr**) array.

Could you load the names dynamically?

as I am a DBA and very less knowledge of scripting thats why I have raised this query.

Could you save the one client's data to a different database?

No its PROD.

Comment: Where do you get the names of the collections that you want to leave untouched? Could you load the names dynamically? Could you save the one client's data to a different database?

Comment: Hi Jiri I have changed my query as per ur questions..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running the code but I think this should point you to the right direction:

```
const codes = db.setup.distinct("SetupCode", {
  ClientID: "5c1cf5e29bbee71ac083b312"
});

db.getCollectionNames()
  .filter(function(name) {
    // Does it end with AggBalance or RecBalance and a number?
    const match = name.match(".*(?:AggBalance|RecBalance)_([0-9]+)$");

    if (!match)
      return true;

    // Convert the match to an actual number and see if it's present in the
    // array
    const code = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    return !codes.includes(code);
  })
  .forEach(function(name) {
    print("About to remove from", name);
    // Test it first!
    // db.getCollection(name).remove({
    //   _id: {
    //     $lt: objectIdWithTimestamp(monthdate)
    //   }
    // });
  });
```

Comment: // Does it end with AggBalance or RecBalance and a number? Yes its end with numbers and starts with RecBalance_xxxx and AggBalances_xxxx......

Comment: script given by you is removing all collections from the DB not working at all also showing TypeError: redeclaration of const codes....

Comment: @YogeshJ Are SetupCodes in the collection actual numbers (or numbers written as strings)?

Comment: @YogeshJ The code I posted doesn't redeclare `codes`. Do you have something else named `codes` in the script?

Comment: Are Setup Codes in the collection actual numbers (or numbers written as strings)? Setup Codes are the numbers and to remove respective name collection if setup code is 223 then collection name will be AggBalances_223 and RecBalance_223.